# How can I remove section headings while using deleteRowsAtIndexPaths to delete rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have a tableview with a number of sections. Each section contains data for a particular day. Each section has a heading saying how many days ago the data was input.

I am trying to delete the section headings once all the rows in that section have been deleted while using deleteRowsAtIndexPath to delete the rows.

When facing the problem I first deleted the data from the array filling the tableview, then refreshed the tableview to update the view after an item had been deleted. This had the issue that there was a horrible jerky transition as the view reloaded.

I decided to use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths which works well and smoothly. This then brought up the issue that when you have deleted all the rows in a section the heading is still left.

So here is the heart of the problem.

If I use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths then the animation is nice but I can't refresh the table after as it ruins the animation. But if I use this then I am left with the section heading after deletion.

If I refresh then the section headings will disappear but the animation is horrible for the user.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
// This is the method done when we go into slide to delete editing
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  // This allows us to calculate what row was clicked rather than the section and row
  NSUInteger row = 0;
  NSUInteger sect = indexPath.section;
  for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < sect; ++ i)
      row += [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
      row += indexPath.row;

  // This gets us the exercise event that has been clicked

  BExerciseEvent * exerciseEvent = _exercise.exerciseEvents[row];

  NSInteger j;

  for (j = 0; j < _exercise.exerciseEvents.count; j++) {
      BExerciseEvent * event = _exercise.exerciseEvents[j];

      if ([exerciseEvent isEqual:event]) {

          // Delete from Database
          [event deleteAllParametersForExerciseEvent];
          [event deleteRow];

          // Delete correct rows from array
          _exerciseEvent = _sections[(indexPath.section - 1)][indexPath.row];
          [_sections[(indexPath.section - 1)] removeObject: _exerciseEvent];

          // Delete from table view
          [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:(indexPath.section)]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

      }
  }

  [super setEditing:NO animated:YES];
  [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
  [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

}

Thanks for any help or advice you can offer

Comment: I believe there's a `deleteSection:` method or something simaliar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to delete the whole section. OF course this means your data source needs to be setup so the section is really gone, not just setup with 0 rows.

Instead of deleting each row, you delete the whole section from the data source then call:

```
[tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:someSection] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```